# Home page without path

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am new to drupal 8, so probably the question is quite silly. I need to create a home page for the website and it should be accessible by the url example.com (without any routes in url). I created a page, via page manager, called it Home page and setted the path "/home" (why I can't stay it empty?). So, ok, I defined the path to the front page in admin/structure/views/view/frontpage and in /admin/config/system/site-information. It works, but when I access the example.com, for some reason the trailing slash is added. How can I remove it?

Comment: are you clear your cache, Drupal has so strong cache that needs to clear it in many cases? and please put some more details on how you configure and anything that may help us to get your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't undestand you about cache. I just want to remove trailing slash in the end of url string, when I access the home page. Now, when I try to access the home page, the url looks like "example.com/", but I want "example.com"